# Wordpress Featured Image URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add the featured image url to the featured image, so it will open up in a lightbox when clicked.

My code is:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<a href="#" target="_blank"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail();} ?></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else: ?>

        <article>

            <h1><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h1>

        </article><!--/ Article -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

I have tried quite a few things but cannot get it to pull the thumbnail URL. I have tried adding these to where the link # is:

```
wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ));
```

...

```
$thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
```

...

```
<?php echo $thumbnailsrc ?>
```

I am sure there is a simple solution that I am yet to find. Thanks to anyone who maybe able to assist :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try this code adding in to your post loop. and confirm you have set feature image for that post which you listings.

```
<?php $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
if(!empty($post_thumbnail_id)) {
$img_ar =  wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'full' ); ?>    
<img src="<?php echo $img_ar[0];?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' )[0]`

Assuming you are in [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), you can simply use `get_post_thumbnail_id()` to get the current post featured image ID. You also need to pass the second parameter `full` in order to get the non-resized version of the image for your lightbox source. You can limit it to large as well, if you like.

Comment: Yes I think I am in the loop but that unfortunately doesn't seem to work. I presume I would add this in PHP tags.

Comment: Yes of course. Try doing `get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() )` instead? (put it within the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` function) Do some debugging on your own to find out if the post ID is returning correctly, followed by if the media ID is returning correctly.

Comment: Oh.. See my updated answer. I think i know the problem, wp_get_attachment_image_src returns an array.